# How to show percentage of script execution in unix

Tags: perl, unix, execution-time

If we run a shell/perl/tcl script in Unix how can we display the percentage of execution in the mean time?

Example:

```
./scriptname
1% Completed the execution of script.pl
2% Completed the execution of script.pl
...
100% Completed the the execution of script.pl
```

and display the execution time taken for the script at the end.

Example output:

```
Execution time for script.pl is :50 Seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, look at the [Smart::Comments](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Smart-Comments-1.0.4/lib/Smart/Comments.pm) module.

And for the elapsed time, simply take the delta of the `time()` at the beginning versus the end.

Answer (score 1):

We've implemented similar progress display with [Time::Progress](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aProgress) module, perhaps you'd check it.

Comment: @user, instead of thanking raina77ow in a comment, you should upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow above the 0 to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

before=`date +%s`

# do task
for i in {1..10}; do
    # do steps
    sleep 1
    # show progress
    echo -ne "${i}0% Completed\r"
done

after=`date +%s`

duration=$((after-before))
echo "Execution time is: $duration Seconds"
```

Comment: As for loop is getting executed after the completed the exectuion of our task, it cannot be beneficial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways you  could do this:

1. The interpreter could support it natively; this isn't something `bash`, `tclsh`, or `perl` do, so you're out of luck.
2. The script could include statements to do it by printing the needed info periodically.

Only the second one is generally applicable. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

as the time a script executes may differ each time (slightly), you need to do this from your script only, as the shell doesn't offer this feature.

i'd recommend to set some "milestones" after each function call or whatever step in your script with an integer that is increased each time by 1 or 0.x

this one may be tough, but it's the only way as far as i'm concerned.